# ArrayList element doesn't sum up correctly

Tags: java, arraylist, sum

I have a problem to sum up my `ArrayList` items' kilometers.

I have initialised the variable `doel2` to `0`. When I first press my button and write in the `km` field `20` then I get `20`, so correct. But when I then fill in for example `20` in my `km` field then I get the value `100` but it must be `40`.

I get in my Java console:

```
file is created  
file closed  
20

file is created  
file is closed  
40  
60  
80  
100
```

Here is the code from the method:

```
public int NogAfTeLeggenKm(){ // methode om nog af te leggen km's te berekenen TODO
    for(Wandeldag w2:wandeldagLijst){
        try {
            doel2=doel2+Integer.valueOf(w2.getKilometer());
            System.out.println(doel2);
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("probeer opnieuw");
        }
    }
    return doel2;
}
```

Here is the code from my `ActionListener`:

```
public class volgendeWandeldag implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e5) {
        Wandelaar.save();//save in text file
        int km = Integer.parseInt(tekstvakKilometer.getText());
        Wandeldag =  new Wandeldag(dag,maand,jaar,aantalUur,aantalMinuten,km); 
        Wandelaar.voegWandeldagToe(Wandeldag);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+Wandelaar);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help if you include the rest of your code too (your main method?).
Where does wandeldagLijst come from? Or the Wandelaar object? How are they initialised.

Also, most people can't really make sense of your code because all the words are in Dutch, and if they cant read it they cant help you.

From what I can understand of your code (and I can read the Dutch words) I think the problem is that every time you call NogAfTeLeggenKilometers(), it loops through all items in the ArrayList, so also through those who were already in the list last time you called the method. Those items will be counted double because 'doel2' is global to this method. Conclusion: 'doel2' should be a local variable.

```
public int NogAfTeLeggenKm(){ // methode om nog af te leggen km's te berekenen TODO
   int res = 0; 
   for(Wandeldag w2:wandeldagLijst){

       try {
           res=res+Integer.valueOf(w2.getKilometer());
           System.out.println(res);
       }
       catch(NullPointerException e){
           System.out.println("probeer opnieuw");
       }
   }
   return res;

}
```

and in your main method you should do:

```
doel2 = NogAfTeLeggenKm();
```

Also: why do you use a try-catch block for assigning a value to a variable?

Comment: Thanks, It works. The variabele doel2 must be indeed a local variabele. When I wan't to use the returned value from the method NogAfTeLeggenKm I have to assign another variabele to the NogAfTeLeggenkm method.

Comment: Had to figure out how to do it (I am new), found it! Thanks again!